# Simple prolog program returns "ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure" when ran

Tags: prolog

Here is the code:

```
bigger(elephant, horse).
bigger(horse, donkey).

is_bigger(X, Y) :-
   bigger(X, Y).
is_bigger(X, Y) :-
   bigger(X, Z),
   is_bigger(Z, Y).
```

it compiles but then I get this

```
57 ?- bigger(elephant, horse).
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: bigger/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)
58 ?- is_bigger(horse, donkey).
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: is_bigger/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you compile the code? It doesn't seem to be loaded.

Comment: I have it in 'G:\test.pl' and i compile it as such: 1 ?- ['G:/test'].

Comment: the compilation output is: % G:/test compiled 0.00 sec, 2 clauses
true

Comment: Your code shows 4 clauses. Could it be that you're compiling a **different** file than the one holding the code above? Is the file saved?

Comment: No it's not that. Actually when I erased the last 2 clauses it would magically be able to compute bigger(elephant, horse). Anyway, I closed Notepad and retyped it from scratch and it now seems to be working. I still don't know what's different. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you loading the file before you query? Can you try `[filename].` ?